# VB excel change color of output "Disabled"

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

How do I change the Font Color if the cell is filled with disabled? Currently I have,

```
If Uservar And 2 Then
    rngOut.Value = "Disabled"
Else
    rngOut.Value = "Enabled"
End If
```

I want "Disabled" to show up red. When I run my excel macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the font color of a cell by using it's .ColorIndex property.

```
If rngOut.Value = "Disabled" Then
    rngOut.Font.ColorIndex = 3
ElseIf rngOut.Value = "Enabled" Then
    '~~> Do Something
End If
```